# How to disable bluetooth connectivity, only advertising

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, movesense

Is there possibility to disable bluetooth connection to Movesense sensor? Use is only advertisement. In App.cpp

```
BLE_COMMUNICATION(false)
```

Disables MDS but connection to sensor is still possible e.g. battery service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That macro is a leftover from early days so pay no attention to it.

There are two parts to making the sensor non-connectable:

1. The advertising must be marked non-connectable (this was implemented in 2.0)
2. If connection is made anyways, it should be immediately disconnected

For disconnecting when connected, you can subscribe to the */Comm/Ble/Peers* and receive a notification every time that the connection is made. Then you can call DELETE on the connection resource (*/Comm/Ble/Peers/*).

See [Movesense BLE-API](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/MovesenseCoreLib/resources/movesense-api/comm/ble.yaml) for more info.

However do notice that this affects all BLE connections and will make updating the sensor firmware much more difficult since you can't then set it to DFU mode without using the DFU recovery process (battery removal).

*Full disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: Thank you. Is there any change with 2.1 related to this? To maximize payload I use advertisement packet without flag, only manufacturer data. Connection is still possible with e.g. nRF Connect which stops advertisement. Related to this any plans for extended advertisement support?

Comment: Not in near future, but if requested by many (via info (at) movesense.com), it would be possible to take on todo-list.

Comment: Actual code was was actually very simple. On WB_RES::PeerStateValues::CONNECTED) just
`asyncDelete(WB_RES::LOCAL::COMM_BLE_PEERS_CONNHANDLE::ID, AsyncRequestOptions::Empty, (int32_t) 0 );` and on disconnect restarting advertisement. 
`            `asyncPost(WB_RES::LOCAL::COMM_BLE_ADV::ID,AsyncRequestOptions::Empty);`

and